# How to display information (gotten from another table) about n items on a report with a query as Control Source?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that essentially shows the parts required to make a finished product. It looks like this[image]

All of the columns in this table represent IDs of parts. In my inventory table, there is information stored about each of these IDs. When I create my report, I want to be able to display the [Ordering Code] beside each ID on the report that looks like this,[image]
So far I've been trying to get this for L1, but if I can get it to work for one it will work for the others. I can get it to show an [Ordering Code] in the textbox, but only the first one (the one that belongs to ID 60). Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim x As DAO.Recordset
Dim w, v As String

w = "SELECT [Ordering Code] FROM inventory WHERE [ID] = " & L1box.Value & ";"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set x = db.OpenRecordset(w)
Text30 = x.Fields(0)
```

And my report design. **My question is**: How can I get the textbox to display the [Ordering Code] that corresponds with each ID instead of just the first one?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're fighting against the natural order of MS Access here.

Within the report its much, much easier to use the `Record Source` as a means of obtaining the data. From there, simply select the Table / Query you want, then use `Text Box` with the `Control Source` set to the columns you are trying to pull data from. The labels of those `Text Box` will serve as the column header.

So, in your instance, you would select the report > (in Property Sheet) use `Record Source` and set it to `AssemblyTree`. Then those `Text Box` you have, set the `Control Source` to `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, etc.

Once those are in place, you would just add another for the `AssemblyID` and it would function as a query would, row by row for the IDs.

Comment: If I set the AssemblyTree as the record source, wouldn't the report just show the whole table? The report works as intended in the current state, only displaying the L1, L2, L3 of the specified AssemblyID, but I want to add the ordering code functionality as well. And since L1-3 are all IDs of parts, they have ordering codes stored in another table, and I want to be able to get this ordering code to display alongside the respective ID in the report. Maybe that helped clarify?

Comment: No, it will only show what you set it up to show (reports work very similiarly to queries, in that you only need to SELECT what you want to). If you want another column for another table in there, you could just write a query to accomplish that (using an Inner Join, assuming the IDs are linked), and then populate the report to that query.